# Android Annotation Code Generation - Android Classes

Tags: android, kotlinpoet

When starting to build my first code generation annotation, I've found I can't generate Android classes, such as `SharedPreferences`, since I start with a `Java Library` module in order to extend `AbstractProcessor`.
I'm using [kotlinpoet](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet) to generate my class, but need to create a property that is of type `SharedPreferences.Editor` which doesn't seem to be supported. I'm trying to something like the following:

```
val editorProperty = PropertySpec.builder("editor", android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor)
```

but this fails since the `android` package is not available.  Does anyone know a workaround for this or is it just not possible?

Comment: You probably need an Android library project and not a Java library project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use

```
PropertySpec.builder("editor",ClassName("android.content", "SharedPreferences.Editor"))
```

as kotlin poet doc says - `Type names are dumb identifiers only and do not model the values they name.`

Comment: Didn't even think about `ClassName`.  And to quote the docs: 
"The `ClassName` type is very important, and you'll need it frequently when you're using KotlinPoet."  haha!  Thank you!